# How do I make pinned items on the Plank respect current workspace only?

Tags: plank

Currently, the implementation of current workspace only for Plank does not extend to any application that is pinned to your dock. This means that Plank will switch your workspace instead of opening a new instance of any pinned application. Is there any way I can change this behaviour so that current workspace only reflects ONLY the current workspace?

Answer (score 3):

You can install Elementary Tweaks:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```

And in the left menu choose Plank and switch this options:

- Current Workspace Only
- Lock Items

Comment: Thanks Alexandre but unfortunately your response is not actually the functionality I was looking for. With the option for current-workspace-only offered through the tweak tool, it does not actually work with respect to items that are pinned to the plank. For example, consider the situation where I have chromium (or any other application) pinned to my plank. If I open it up in workspace one and then switch into a different workspace and click on the chromium icon in the plank it will take me back to the first workspace. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Oh i see, there's a workaround for that, see here https://evertrickz.wordpress.com/2015/06/03/how-to-get-rid-of-duplicate-google-chrome-icon-on-dock-elementary-os/. Also if you open another window from the App Launcher, that window will be attached to your pinned icon, but that's not the ideal solution.